# macOS: ls command stopped working

Tags: terminal, osx

On my macOS (10.11.6) terminal, I did some installations on python virtual env. After that my `ls` command stopped working.
It is giving an error:

```
$ ls
ls: illegal option -- -
usage: ls [-ABCFGHLOPRSTUWabcdefghiklmnopqrstuwx1] [file ...]

$ alias ls
alias ls='colourify ls --color'
```

Comment: Just `unalias ls`

Comment: `unalias ls` works but then I've to run this command each time I open a new terminal window. Which program really messed up with my `ls` cmd in the first place, is it python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Homebrew updated to new version of grc 1.10_1 and this issue is solved.

Answer (score 6):

> Which program really messed up with my `ls` cmd in the first place, is it python?

Your `ls` command is untouched.  Your `ls` **alias** most likely comes from an erroneous Bourne Again shell setup.

Note that your `ls` alias is running a command named `grc`, via another alias named `colourify`.  This comes from [Radovan Garabík's Generic Colourizer](http://kassiopeia.juls.savba.sk/~garabik/software/grc.html), whose Bourne Again shell aliases (in [`grc.bashrc`](https://github.com/garabik/grc/blob/master/grc.bashrc)) and Z shell aliases (in [`grc.zsh`](https://github.com/garabik/grc/blob/master/grc.zsh)) set up an alias named `ls`.

Somewhere, in an rc file, you are adding these aliases to your interactive Bourne Again shell, per recommendations like [this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33363572/340790).

The Z shell alias is

```
alias ls="grc --colour=auto ls"
```

which passes the `--colour-auto` option to the `grc` command, which is the command that takes that option.

However, The Bourne Again shell alias is

```
alias ls='colourify ls --color'
```

which is (via the `colourify` alias) effectively

```
alias ls='grc -es --colour=auto ls --color'
```

which is *both* running the output of the `ls` command through a colourizer *and* trying to get the `ls` command to colourize its output.

The basic problem is that the author of these Bourne Shell aliases ([which was Isaias Piña from Oracle in May 2016](https://github.com/garabik/grc/commit/9374a08e1774ff96d6b8a5ef4878eed687b791fa#diff-e2b5699f9dbcbf3d35fa0c014e7a70fd)) hasn't catered for running the Bourne Again shell on anything other than a Linux operating system, probably expecting that if you are using MacOS you are using something like Oh My Zsh.  An additional problem is that the author hasn't allowed for `grc` to colourize the output of `ls` and is, rather, expecting `ls` to colourize its own output.

So you have a number of options:

- Find where you are adding these aliases and fix Isaias Piña's erroneous `ls` alias to use the `-G` option on MacOS.
- Find where you are adding these aliases and fix Isaias Piña's erroneous `ls` alias to not use any option and instead rely upon the colourizer's `conf.ls` file to do its actual job; [as Tom Mulder has](https://github.com/darkseed/dotfiles/blob/master/_bashrc.aliases#L108).
- Find where you are adding these aliases and remove Isaias Piña's erroneous `ls` alias entirely, using the `CLICOLOR` environment variable for colourization instead; [as Noel B Alonso does](https://www.nbalonso.com/shell-where-i-work/).
- Find where you are adding these aliases and remove Isaias Piña's erroneous `ls` alias entirely, using your own `ls` alias; [as Arthur Nisnevich does](https://github.com/ArthurN/dotfiles/blob/master/.bash/aliases.sh#L34).
- Uninstall the Generic Colourizer entirely.
- Use the Z shell.

Comment: I'm using simple bash. I had two lines added to my ~/.profile and they were working for ~5 years:  
`alias ll='ls -GFhl'  
source "$(brew --prefix)/etc/grc.bashrc"`
The last couple of days, I added imagemagick7 and brew updates happened. They may have caused some of the ls troubles

Answer (score 4):

I just updated iTerm2 to version `Build 3.0.14` and ran into this issue. The command `ls` from coreutils was no longer in my path. After running:

```
brew install coreutils
```

and opening a new shell the problem was fixed. I have the following alias in my ~/.bashrc:

```
export LS_OPTS='--color=auto'
alias ls='ls ${LS_OPTS}'
```

Answer (score 3):

macOS (Darwin) `ls` doesn't support the `--color` option. Did/do you have another copy of `coreutils` installed from something like homebrew, macports, or pkgsrc that is now gone or changed order in your `PATH`?

Comment: But my `ls` was working with `--color` option for over 5 years. I had homebrew but no coreutils installed.

Answer (score 1):

Using homebrew, install `coreutils` and add the coreutils to the PATH：

```
brew install coreutils
export PATH="/usr/local/opt/coreutils/libexec/gnubin:$PATH"
```

Source：https://github.com/sorin-ionescu/prezto/issues/966.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it turned out I was attempting to delete a whole lot of `.zip` files with dashes in their names.

`man rm` mentions using `--` to prevent the command from processing further options.

```
rm -rf -- *.zip
```

Did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

```
if ls --help 2>&1 | grep -q -- --color
then
    alias ls='ls --color=auto -F'
else
    alias ls='ls -FG'
fi
```

This magic snippet from https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/342168/287064 fixed it for me.

I think it has to do with macOS's BSD vs GNU versions of `ls`.