# Remove bold fonts from zsh

Tags: osx, zsh, oh-my-zsh

I just started using zsh and oh-my-zsh in the default macOS terminal. When using

```
$ ls
```

(or related commands like `la` or `ll`) names of directories are displayed in bold font. Is there a possibility to disable bold fonts for zsh, e.g. in `.zshrc`? Also I'm interested in a possibility to change to color of the printed directory names.

Comment: A related question is https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/342599/ .

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot derive an answer to my question from the linked one.

Answer (score 2):

In both **Terminal** and **iTerm** there is a switch in Preferences to turn off bold fonts. This is shown for terminal here:

[image: terminal_boldfonts.jpeg]

And for iTerm here:

[image: iterm_boldfonts.jpeg]

Go to Terminal menu item or the iTerm2 menu item and click on preferences.